# Google App Script Permissions, excessive?

Tags: google-apps-script, permissions

Why do all Google Apps Scripts require so many permissions? This screenshot is from a test script I made. Should I worry that 3rd party apps also have the ability to delete spreadsheets (or emails or whatever app the script is accessing)?

Or is it just to delete the spreadsheet I am working on? Some scripts say all files in Google Drive. Who wants to give any app that much control? In practise, would any 3rd party developer actually go through with this? It almost sounds like giving programmers the ability to hack our accounts? Am I not understanding this?

Here is an example of a 3rd party app. Do they seriously need all those permissions just to send out an email from a Google Sheet? Seems excessive! Can I, after the fact, restrict the permissions as other authors have said, just a few minutes ago?[image]

I don't see the point.

[image]

Comment: Possible duplicate [How to narrow scopes for Google Apps Script to specific files](https://stackoverflow.com/q/57564199/1595451)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If you created the script from a spreadsheet, you can declare the following (add it the top of your script) to only grant access to that spreadsheet:

```
/**
 * @OnlyCurrentDoc
 */
```

See also https://developers.google.com/apps-script/guides/services/authorization.

Comment: Can I do this for 3rd party apps too?

Comment: If you're installing an add-on from the Marketplace, no. The developer would have to do this.

Comment: So it's back to teaching myself apps script. Thanks @mary 2