Setting access rights for Google Script
I have a file upload form in my table. After pressing the button, a form opens, I choose a file and the script moves it to the desired folder.
The problem is that in order to activate the script, I need to give it permission to work with all the files on my disk.
Is there a way to give the script permission to run in a specific folder?
I know about the function @OnlyCurrentDoc, but as far as I understand it will only restrict access to the table, not all files.

Related: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/57564199

Can you share your codes  or code blocks for us to check if this problem is not yet answered by the community?

If this script will be used only by you, from a pragmatical point of view, you might be trying to solve a problem that doesn't exist. This question might be derived from unclear concepts in Google Apps Script, but there are not enough details, which makes this question too broad for Stack Overflow. Please add more information about how your script will be used, specifically if this is only to be used by you or if you will share the script with others.

@user27425627 It's from staging ground and closed as duplicate. I was not satisfied with either the duplicate reasoning or the answer of that question and therefore voted to post on main site.

Using drive.file scope,  you can either

use Google picker(sample) with ViewId: FOLDERS to grant access to a specific folder  in Google drive.

or create a new folder with this script(maybe possible  only via api), which would give you access to that folder from that script with this scope.


